# Is there anyway to use stripe recipients, even though its deprecated?

Tags: android, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am using Stripe Api in my Android Application.

When did stripe api deprecate its "recipients" functionality?

Is there a way around to still being use this functionality from android application?

please, response as quick as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing Stripe account that used the feature you can continue using it.  I have an app this is still using it in late 2016.  Apparently new accounts cannot enable recipients.